# Android: Resetting repeating AlarmManager from within called service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat

I've set a repeating alarm on a service and decided that it's most convenient to reset the alarm from within the called service. The reason is that the service already has code to check if it's within a user-defined schedule (time range). When it's outside the time range, it resets the alarm to start at the future time selected by the user.  Maybe I'm approaching this wrong but I'll put this question out there and see what you think.

An activity kicks off the service by creating a repeating alarm:

```
//Activity
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("MyService://identifier"));
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            intervalInMins*60000, pIntent);
```

The service has something like this:

```
//Service
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Uri Action = intent.getData();
    try {
        if (Action.equals(Uri.parse("MyService://identifier"))) {
            //Simplifying the code here: CalculatedOffset is determined from the current time
            //and scheduled start time. intervalInMins is read from settings.
            if (!WithinSchedule()) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + CalculatedOffset,
                        intervalInMins*60000, pIntent);
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException np) {
        np.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

I was hoping to re-use the intent to reset the repeating alarm. With this new code, I'm seeing multiple alarms stack up firing rapidly in succession around when the start time hits. It should not spaz out like that, but should fire at regular intervals as it did before the scheduling reset. I need to catch it in the debugger but haven't been able to determine the exact conditions yet. Is my understanding of alarms completely off base here? Is there a better way to do this?

Addendum: A wrinkle in this is that I'm using RootTools to gain superuser privileges in order to work around Android 4.2's airplane mode. This hasn't been a problem before the scheduling, but I'm suspicious whether su is blocking for a long time while the alarms stack up.

Comment: I wonder, when replacing a repeating alarm, is it required to use PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT when creating the PendingIntent? I've been using 0 all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-using the intent inside the service that receives the alarm does work. I've switched from using a Repeating Alarm to a single-shot alarm which gets re-armed every time the service is called. Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem of the alarms stacking. The culprit is definitely su blocking. It may be RootTools or su itself. I need to update the library from 2.6 to 3.x and see if that makes any difference.